# Adjective for a person who is constantly full of wonder/awe

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, loanwords

I'm sure you've met someone like this; a person whose understanding of nature, structure and the universe leaves them constantly awed by the complexity of practically everything.

I'm looking for a word (English or borrowed) that describes a person with that constant elation of someone who has lived half a life in a small flat in a dull city but is suddenly taken on an all expenses paid round-the-world tour.

Awe and Wonder are nouns that I think convey this meaning, but the naïve verb equivalents (awful & wonderful) don't fit the bill.

Any ideas?

@sumelic makes an excellent clarification point: I'm specifically looking for a word that implies "I would expect them to be awestruck often in the future" whether or not they are presently.

Comment: awestruck not awful :)

Comment: Do you want a word specifically related to "awe" or "wonder," or are those just examples? "Awed" is a word. Also, is the "constant" part very important? (You mention it twice.) Synonyms of "astonished" seem relevant to me, but there are so many that I don't know which one to suggest: amazed, astounded, dazzled,... http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/astonished

Comment: Awestruck is definitely closer, as is awed, but @sumelic has the key point for me (I'll clarify above): the continuing state; I would expect that this person would be awestruck often in the future, whether or not they presently are.

Answer (score 4):

How about [**wide-eyed**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wide-eyed):

> = staring, spellbound, gobsmacked (British) (slang), dumbfounded, agog, agape, thunderstruck, goggle-eyed, awe-stricken

It's usually used to describe an instant reaction, but I think it works as a description of character: part impressionable, part naive, part optimistic.

Comment: This is the closest I've found in my online & offline searches! It's not perfect, as you've mentioned it has strong "instant reaction" connotations, but it's so close :)

Answer (score 1):

If the person is constantly awestruck by things that others consider unremarkable or mundane, he is said to have

- a **childlike** sense of wonder
  (or *wonderment*)

http://i.word.com/idictionary/wonderment

This evokes an image of innocence—of being struck with wonder as if seeing the (whatever) *for the first time*.

Or, you could simply say that (in reference to encountering these awe-inspiring things), he is **childlike**

(NOT *childish*!)

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly the sense I'm looking for, though I'm looking for a single adjective, rather than a descriptive phrase.

Comment: Sadly I feel like "childlike", though descriptive in the way I'm looking for in some contexts, carries too much additional meaning akin to "immature".